# iOS Firebase Messaging Not Working for User Segments

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been using Firebase Messaging (sent through the Firebase dashboard) for months through multiple projects with no problem and I LOVE it, however in the last week I have run into an issue where I cannot get notifications to go through to iOS for user segments for newly set up projects. If it was just one project then I would assume I had configured something wrong, but I am on round 3 and still having issues.

I have generated p12 files and I have even retrieved FCM registration IDs and successfully sent notifications to specific devices, but when I target the User Segment for iOS, push notifications never go through.

I would be very thankful if anyone has any feedback on this topic. There isn't much more to say since I am successfully getting notifications to specific devices so I believe that should signify that things are configured correctly with APNS (though I am VERY open to hearing someone let me know that I am wrong in that assumption).

Thanks!

Comment: Have you make sure that the users are registered to the specific segments?

Comment: I think that you are referring to Topics when it comes to registering for a segment. In this case, I am just trying to push to iOS as a whole. For Firebase, you can target devices (using a FCM Registration ID), Topics (by subscribing a user to a topic), and user segments (which are platforms like iOS and Android). For Topics, the app needs to subscribe the user, but for user segments, I think the user gets the notification no matter what as long as notifications are enabled (and notifications are enabled seeing as I get them if the notification targets my specific device).

Comment: You are right.. My apologies, what does it say in your notificaitions console, what's the status of the message, does it even show up?

Comment: No problem! I really appreciate the response since I am tearing my hair out and desperate to get this resolved for multiple projects. In response to your questions, for every push, the Status is "Completed" with a checkmark.

Comment: I am experiencing this exact issue. Did you upgrade to xcode 9 perhaps?

Comment: Nope! I am still running 8.3.2 because I am in middle of all of these projects and don't want to add more potential problems on top of it. Are you thinking the problem could be because I am not running Xcode 9? Also, you mentioned that you are experiencing the issue. Have you had success in the past and just recently found that new projects aren't working while old ones still do? And are you able to push to specific devices but not to segments (iOS as a whole for instance)? I'm trying to figure out how similar your scenario is to mine. Thanks for the response!